# What factors do influence the Catalyst app restart mechanism? (Firebird connection)

Tags: perl, firebird, catalyst

I have a problem like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077483/what-factors-do-influence-the-catalyst-app-restart-mechanism)

> I have a Perl Catalyst application which is launched normally using
>   the -r parameter. I have noticed 2 types of behaviour:
>
> 1) the application restarts normally on every "dummy change" of the
>   code (by "dummy change" I mean adding a space or deleting one, smth
>   like this)
>
> 2) the application doesn't restart (the same "dummy change"), the
>   "Attempting to restart the server" text is displayed and the app
>   remains blocked in this state (I have to kill it manually)
>
> The behaviour depends on the actual code. It seems there is something
>   related to the code which influences which behaviour acts at one
>   moment. The behaviour is constant, i.e. the same code have one
>   constant behaviour of 2. The application itself seems to work fine,
>   without any errors or warnings.
>
> How could the code influence this behaviour? (I mean generally) What
>   factors are related to restart mechanism?

But I don't have connection to OracleDB, I have connection to Firebird DB through DBD::Firebird.